# annotating a model of mongoose type in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have a function called createFactory, it expects two arguments, a model, and a data object.
this function will create the document with a given data.

```
const createFactory = (Model, obj: object) => {
    Model.create(obj)
}
```

However, TypeScript is warning me because Model have is not typed (annotated, or whatever the term used is).
VScode is not showing code completions for Model when I write "Model." and I hit ctrl+space, VScode is not showing code completions for that reason.

How can write this code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can import some of the definitions from the mongoose package and use them to annotate your function.  It is still a bit complicated though!

```
import {Model, Document, CreateQuery} from "mongoose";

const createFactory = <T extends Document>(model: Model<T>, obj: CreateQuery<T>) => {
    return model.create(obj);
}
```

Your `Model` needs to be a valid mongoose model, so we import the `Model` interface.  This interface is a generic depending on the document type `T` which must extend the base `Document` interface.  Not every possibly `object` is valid as as a argument for `create` so we need to be more specific. Mongoose defines a type `CreateQuery<T>` representing all possible values which can be used to create a document of type `T`.